# Gives Error : "Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code." for worked virtual host when restarting apache2

Tags: server, apache2, ssl, virtualhost

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I was properly working with my project and today morning I have reinstalled apache and php7.0. I have used ssl in my project. When I remove ssl from the virtual host, it worked fine. But when I add ssl again it give the above error. I have tried suggestions that have been given for above error. Non of then are worked. Can anyone help me. Thnak you in advance
output of `sudo systemctl status apache2.service`

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since සි 2017-04-21 08:35:19 +0530; 26s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 3776 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3114 ExecReload=/etc/init.d/apache2 reload (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 3802 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

 අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc apache2[3802]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
 අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc apache2[3802]: Output of config test was:
 අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc apache2[3802]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 34 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/TestCodeIgniter.local.conf:
 අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc apache2[3802]: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in t
 අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc apache2[3802]: Action 'configtest' failed.
 අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc apache2[3802]: The Apache error log may have more information.
 අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
 අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
 අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
 අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Output of `sudo journalctl -xe`

```
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
-- Subject: Unit apache2.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit apache2.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc sudo[3770]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:19 shyamali-pc systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:45 shyamali-pc sudo[3822]: shyamali : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/shyamali ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl status apache2.s
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:35:45 shyamali-pc sudo[3822]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:36:46 shyamali-pc pkexec[3837]: pam_unix(polkit-1:session): session opened for user root by (uid=1000)
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:36:46 shyamali-pc pkexec[3837]: pam_systemd(polkit-1:session): Cannot create session: Already running in a session
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:36:46 shyamali-pc pkexec[3837]: shyamali: Executing command [USER=root] [TTY=unknown] [CWD=/home/shyamali] [COMMAND=/usr/lib/
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:37:17 shyamali-pc sudo[3822]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:39:01 shyamali-pc CRON[3859]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:39:01 shyamali-pc CRON[3860]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && /usr/lib/php/sessionclean)
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:39:02 shyamali-pc CRON[3859]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:41:51 shyamali-pc AptDaemon[2213]: INFO: Quitting due to inactivity
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:41:51 shyamali-pc AptDaemon[2213]: INFO: Quitting was requested
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:41:51 shyamali-pc org.debian.apt[564]: 08:41:51 AptDaemon [INFO]: Quitting due to inactivity
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:41:51 shyamali-pc org.debian.apt[564]: 08:41:51 AptDaemon [INFO]: Quitting was requested
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:43:50 shyamali-pc systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of        Temporary Directories...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun starting up.
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:43:50 shyamali-pc systemd-tmpfiles[3943]: [/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/var.conf:14] Duplicate line for path "/var/log", ignoring.
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:43:50 shyamali-pc systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished starting up.
-- 
-- The start-up result is done.
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:44:53 shyamali-pc sudo[3950]: shyamali : TTY=pts/2 ; PWD=/home/shyamali ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
අප්<U+200D>රි 21 08:44:53 shyamali-pc sudo[3950]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
lines 1108-1149/1149 (END)
```

**Note : Recently I have Installed skype and today I have rove it. But the problem remains as same. These outputs are after removing skype**

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/702899) your question and add the output of `sudo systemctl status apache2.service` and `sudo journalctl -xe`.

Comment: I have add what you asked for.  Thank you for your help. Recently I have Installed skype and today I have rove it. But the problem remains as same. These outputs are after removing skype

Comment: I thinks the problem is with ssl

Comment: There is written `Syntax error on line 34 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/TestCodeIgniter.local.conf`. What have on this line? And when you `sudo a2dissite TestCodeIgniter.local.conf`could start Apache normally?

Comment: In that line `RewriteEngine On`.
when a2dissite it, it gives same error for another virtual host. These errors are only for ssl virtual hosts. When a2dissite all virtual hosts with ssl, apache restarts normally. Thank you

Comment: Maybe [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/module-dict.html#Status) is disabled for some reason. Try to enable it - `sudo a2enmod rewrite`, and restart Apache.

Comment: Well thank you. Now apache restarting without errors. But only load the homepage. Non of other links work. Can you give a solution for this issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57453/discussion-between-spas-spasov-and-shyamali).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The report of `sudo systemctl status apache2.service` shows:

```
Syntax error on line 34 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/TestCodeIgniter.local.conf:
Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in ...
```

For some reason the Apache's module [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/module-dict.html#Status) is disabled. The solution of this particular issue is enabling of the module:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```